# How might I scape table information using Python BeautifulSoup when the table is dynamically generated?

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get earnings calendar information without using yahoo or nasdaq since they are not always accurate.

Bloomberg's website has earnings information at the following url:
https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/earnings-calendar/us

When I inspect the html source for the page, I found the html code block that controls the date picking calendar tool and inspected the some of the event code that I've marked EV#1, EV#2, EV#3, and EV#4 for reference.

```
<div data-view-uid="1|0_5_9_1"> <----EV#1
    <div class="date-picker">  <--EV#2
        <input id="datepicker" value="04/10/2018" class="hasDatepicker" type="text"> <--EV#3
        <button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger">button</button> <----EV#4
    </div>
</div>
```

I've found that each of these EV#n events refer to some jQuery code that handle click events.

When I highlight the event related toolbox in the web inspector at each EV#n, I see code descriptions with either JQuery or Bubbling, DOM2.

I have no idea what these mean, but perhaps it's not so important at this stage. I've included the descriptions and which EV#'s correspond to the code below. Perhaps it is helpful..

**JQuery: (EV#1)**

```
tellMeTheSelectedDate: function() {
r.locale(this.locale);
var e = this.$datePicker().datepicker("getDate"),
t = r(e).format("L");
a.log(t)
}
```

**Bubbling, DOM2: (EV#1, EV#2, EV#3, EV#4)**

```
function An(e) {
  if (Gi) {
    var t = Cn(e);
    if (t && this.id == t.id) {
      var n = In(t);
      if (n && kn(e)) {
        var r = Rn(n);
        r.PX263 = d(t), re("PX217", r), ji++, Fi <= ji && (Gi = !1, Dn(!1))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Bubbling, DOM2: (EV#1, EV#4)**

```
u = b.handle = function(e) {
return typeof d === R || e && d.event.triggered === e.type ? void 
0 : d.event.dispatch.apply(u.elem, arguments)
}
```

**jQuery: (EV#4)**

```
function() {
return e.datepicker._datepickerShowing && 
e.datepicker._lastInput === t[0] ? e.datepicker._hideDatepicker() 
: e.datepicker._datepickerShowing && e.datepicker._lastInput !== 
t[0] ? (e.datepicker._hideDatepicker(), 
e.datepicker._showDatepicker(t[0])) : 
e.datepicker._showDatepicker(t[0]), !1
}
```

**GOAL:**

I have no experience with JQuery, but I know it uses CSS descriptors to dynamically alter web content.

Is it possible for me to use Requests and send a "picked date" (a date string) to the date picking widget by modifying whatever variable stores this value from the calendar tool so that the page refreshes(is this right?) and displays earnings information in the table based on the date I have passed via script?

Would I need to emulate a "click" event to get the page to update with my date?

Getting the data from the table using bs4 is no issue, but my main problem is the date selection.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open developer tools in your browser (F12) and go to the network tab, you can sniff out the request the page is making when you change the date on the calendar.  In doing so, you can pass in whichever date you like as a URL parameter:

```
https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/calendar/earnings/US?locale=en&date=2018-04-30
```