# Python Web Scraping: Interacting with calendar

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using the following url I have managed to parse all the table content by accessing the iframe object.

http://www.b3.com.br/en_us/market-data-and-indices/data-services/market-data/historical-data/derivatives/trading-session-settlements/

However, I am now trying to interact with the calendar that can be found in the top of the page but with no success. The idea is to be able to parse different dates of data form a single python script.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: " ...but with no success." <- Can you show us what you've tried? We really can't help you with this without context.

Comment: I am not an expert in HTML or jacascript so I looked for people with a similar problems. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49745973/how-might-i-scape-table-information-using-python-beautifulsoup-when-the-table-is   But in my case, when I update the date in the calendar I cant find the same request from the web. I didn't think this context was necessary since I am looking for any solution to my problem and this doesnt seem to be one.

Answer (score 0):

The required table can be obtained by doing a `request.post()` and setting the `dData1` parameter with your required date. For example, the following shows how two possible dates could be display. It prints the first few rows of data from each date:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-ajustes-do-pregao-enUS.asp'
dates = ['02/01/2019', '01/03/2019']

for date in dates:
    req = requests.post(url, {'dData1' : date})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

    print(f'\n{date}\n')

    for tr in soup.table.find_all('tr')[1:10]:
        row = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.find_all('td')]
        print(row)
```

This would display the following, which you could use to do your processing:

```
02/01/2019

['AFS   - Futures', 'G19', '13,270.000', '13,270.000', '0.000', '0.00']
['', 'H19', '13,356.000', '13,353.100', '-2.900', '29.00']
['', 'J19', '13,407.300', '13,402.000', '-5.300', '53.00']
['', 'K19', '13,459.500', '13,455.200', '-4.300', '43.00']
['ARB   - Argentinian peso', 'G19', '98.4420', '98.4420', '0.0000', '0.00']
['', 'H19', '94.9590', '95.5790', '0.6200', '93.00']
['', 'J19', '92.1780', '92.5210', '0.3430', '51.45']
['', 'K19', '89.3970', '89.8380', '0.4410', '66.15']
['AUD   - Australian dollar', 'G19', '2,662.7830', '2,662.7830', '0.0000', '0.00']

01/03/2019

['AFS   - Futures', 'G19', '14,452.900', '14,332.500', '-120.400', '1,204.00']
['', 'H19', '14,499.900', '14,381.300', '-118.600', '1,186.00']
['', 'J19', '14,555.900', '14,435.000', '-120.900', '1,209.00']
['ARB   - Argentinian peso', 'G19', '97.5170', '96.1230', '-1.3940', '209.10']
['', 'H19', '92.8950', '91.4710', '-1.4240', '213.60']
['', 'J19', '89.9980', '88.7480', '-1.2500', '187.50']
['AUD   - Australian dollar', 'G19', '2,674.0940', '2,638.5800', '-35.5140', '2,130.84']
['', 'H19', '2,681.9240', '2,645.7490', '-36.1750', '2,170.50']
['', 'J19', '2,689.0940', '2,652.6630', '-36.4310', '2,185.86']
```

The URL being used was found by watching the URL requested by the page when a date was entered.